# How to automatically fix lighting conditions in different shots in a timelapse?

Tags: time-lapse

I'm taking a timelapse with 30 minutes between each picture. Around 55 pictures, that all need to match their lighting conditions. Around 40 or so are already the same, but is there an automatic  way to match the last 15?

Answer (score 2):

There are plugins that adjust exposure over time to reduce flickering in timelapses - [GBDeflicker works well](http://granitebaysoftware.com/Products/ProductGBD.aspx). (But it won't change night to day or anything like that).

See also:
[Correcting exposure flickering in time-lapse footage "in post"](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/correcting-exposure-flickering-in-time-lapse-footage-in-post/4362#4362)

Comment: The exposure's the same in all photos, however, the lighting is different in many of them. I can manually fix the worst ones.